# "Draw" rectangles around multiple other rectangles to achieve backdrop effect

Tags: geometry, area, rectangles

**Note:** I will use the word *overlay* interchangeably with *backdrop*.

**Note 2:** This is a programming problem with CSS/Javascript. Each of these boxes have or can have width/height and top/left/right/bottom offsets in pixels. So those would be the values that can be calculated with.

I'm currently working on a guide mode and I highlight elements to make them stand out from the darker semi-transparent background.

So basically, I have **one box** that I want to not be overlaid/covered, and then I surround it with semi-transparent dark rectangles, simulating an overlay with an excluded element.

To do that, I simply do the following calculations:

**Rectangle one (surround from top):**

- Draw from the starting top position (top: 0)
- Draw from the starting left position (left: 0)
- Width is 100% of the container
- Height is the **top** offset of the box that I want excluded

**Rectangle two (surround from left):**

- The starting top position would be the offset of the box. (top: box's offset)
- Draw from the starting left position (left: 0)
- The width would be the left offset of the box. So basically from distance from the start of the container to the box itself.
- The height would be the height of the box

**Rectangle three (surround from bottom):**

- The starting top position would be: The box's offset + the box's height
- The left position would be again 0 (left: 0)
- Width is 100% of the container
- Height would be basically 100% below the point from where it's being drawn, so the remainder of the container.

**Rectangle four (surround from right):**

- The top would be again the top offset of the box
- The left position would be the box's left offset + the box's width (or we can simply take the box's right offset)
- The width would be 100% from the starting point and to the right until the container is filled up
- The height would be the box's height.

To illustrate this:

[image: example 1]

My solution works great for one highlighted box, but when that number becomes 2+, it becomes hard to calculate how to place the surrounding rectangles around those boxes. And the issue is: The boxes might need to be spread across the container, so the surrounding with boxes will vary a lot. There is no single static solution on my case.

So to illustrate my issue:

[image: example 2]

Here you can see the different boxes that need to be put into the page in order to surround Box1 and Box2 with the semi-transparent dark rectangles, basically simulating the overlay effect with highlighted elements. For one case like this one, I can *hardcode* the calculations and everything would be fine, but **what if** Box1 was higher up than Box2? Then what if they were not overlapping each other horizontally anymore? What if there is a Box3 that needs highlighting?

In either case, I wouldn't know how many dark boxes to place and where to place them.

Is there any mathematical formula that would help me in this case?

How would I approach this problem and make it extendable (multiple boxes, different positions)?

As noted above, this problem stems from a programming project. I tried to convert the programming terms and make them as generic as possible. If there is anything unclear, please let me know and I will clarify.

Comment: In mathematical terms please define what is given and what is required.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344906/creating-a-hole-in-a-div-element. Why are you asking on math.SE instead of SO?